# Inserting form input into mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im trying to insert Room name and Room status which is submitted from my form into my Rooms collection in mongoose database. When I click submit, a new room is inserted with the dateCreated and dateEdited but the room name and status are not inserted into database.

Room model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var room = new mongoose.Schema({
    room: String,
    created: {type:Date, default:Date},
    edited: {type:Date, default:Date},
    status: String
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("Room", room);
```

Room.js (form code):

```
<Modal visible={this.state.visible} width="400" height="300" effect="fadeInUp" onClickAway={()=>this.closeModal}>
            <div>
                <form method="POST" action="/api/room">
                  <label>Room name: </label>
                  <input type='text' placeholder="Room name" name="roomName" required/>  <br></br>
                  <label>Status: &emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </label>
                  <select id="sel1" name="status" required>
                  <option>Active</option>
                  <option>Inactive</option>
                  </select>
                  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>       
                </form>
                <button onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
            </div>
            </Modal>
```

Room.js route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Rooms = require('../models/Rooms');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use(bodyParser.json())
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));



/* GET ALL ROOMS */
router.get('/api/room', function(req, res, next) {
  Rooms.find((err, results)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
  });
}); 

/* SAVE ROOMS */

router.post("/api/room", (req,res)=>{
  var data = new Rooms(req.body);
  console.log(data);
  data.save()
    .then(item=>{
      res.send('room added to db');
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      res.status(400).send("unable to save to db")
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: The form data is probably not parsing correctly on the server-side. For example, in your front-end form the room name is `roomName` while in the DB schema it is `room`. What are you getting in the log from `console.log(data)`?

Comment: I get SAVED { _id: 5cb14a7dd43901150033b613,
  status: 'Active',
  created: 2019-04-13T02:33:33.000Z,
  edited: 2019-04-13T02:33:33.000Z }

Comment: yeah so either change the name on the input element to `room` or update your schema to `roomName` should get you the name property. Also you are using both `Room` and `Rooms` in different places. Not sure if it's a copy and paste error or an actual typo from your project.